# Getting 0 values through getters in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i have my getters and setters in one Package
I'm setting the values in  a class which is in different package
and I'm trying to get the values from the class which is again in separate package.
but I'm getting zero values please help me out with that issue.

```
    package com.company.pojo;

    public class ExamplePojo {


private int x;
private int y;
private int z;

private String a;
private String b;
private String c;

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
public int getY() {
    return y;
}
public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}
public int getZ() {
    return z;
}
public void setZ(int z) {
    this.z = z;
}
public String getA() {
    return a;
}
public void setA(String a) {
    this.a = a;
}
public String getB() {
    return b;
}
public void setB(String b) {
    this.b = b;
}
public String getC() {
    return c;
}
public void setC(String c) {
    this.c = c;
}
```

}

Another package where I am setting the values is

```
    package com.company.function;

    import com.company.pojo.ExamplePojo;

    public class SetValue {

ExamplePojo EP = null;

public void setValue(){

     EP = new ExamplePojo();

    EP.setX(10);
    EP.setY(20);
    EP.setZ(30);
    EP.setC("Saurabh");
    EP.setA("mahaesh");
    EP.setB("Kanni");
}

}
```

and in the third package I'm trying to get the values through getters where it is returning me 0.

```
    package com.company.Execute;

    import com.company.function.SetValue;
    import com.company.pojo.ExamplePojo;

    public class Main {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    SetValue St = new SetValue();
    St.setValue();
    ExamplePojo EP = new ExamplePojo();

    System.out.println(EP.getX());
    System.out.println(EP.getY());
    System.out.println(EP.getZ());
    System.out.println(EP.getA());
    System.out.println(EP.getB());
    System.out.println(EP.getC());
}
```

}

Output is

```
          0
          0
          0
          null
          null
          null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to what @NPE said, your problem is that you are managing two different object.

This is a possible way to do what you are looking for...

Modify:

```
package com.company.function;

import com.company.pojo.ExamplePojo;

public class SetValue {

  public ExamplePojo setValue(){

    ExamplePojo EP = new ExamplePojo();

    EP.setX(10);
    EP.setY(20);
    EP.setZ(30);
    EP.setC("Saurabh");
    EP.setA("mahaesh");
    EP.setB("Kanni");

    return EP;
  }

}
```

Change:

```
SetValue St = new SetValue();
ExamplePojo EP = St.setValue();
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have two separate objects, `St.EP` and `EP`. You change one and then examine the other:

```
SetValue St = new SetValue();       //
St.setValue();                      // this changes St.EP
ExamplePojo EP = new ExamplePojo(); //
System.out.println(EP.getX());      // this examines EP
```

Comment: i will be really thankful to you if Can you show one example how you want me to execute it may be with this example only.

Comment: If i remove SetValue St = new SetValues(); and St.setValue(); then also I am getting zero result

Comment: @Saurabh Check my answer, i gave you an option how to modify your code in relation to what NPE said.